# Cannot install python packages due to missing site-packages folder on Linux

Tags: python, linux, pip

On Linux, every time I try to install a python package I get an error that the site-packages directory is missing. For example:

```
error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/opt/python/cp39-cp39/Lib/site-packages/'
```

One simple solution is to just create the missing directory; however, this is not possible in certain instances. For example, when running `python -m build`, a venv with a random name is created to build the package in - therefore, I cannot create the site-package folder since there is no pause where I can modify the new venv.

I have tested this on multiple machines, and this issue also appears in GitHub hosted CI/CD runners. This is especially difficult to resolve in CI/CD pipelines because I have no control over additional venvs created by `build`, `cibuildwheel` and other PyPA tools.

This error occurs when I run `pip install .`, `python -m build` and several other pip commands that involve building wheel packages. The error always occurs while pip is building the wheel.

I would appreciate any suggestions!

Comment: How did you install Python?  I've never seen one that installs in `/opt/python`.  It's always `/usr/lib` or `/usr/local/lib`.

Comment: What pip command(s) are you running exactly that cause this problem? Is this the full output or is there more? Please try to make a [mre].

Comment: @TimRoberts That was an error from [cibuildwheel](https://github.com/pypa/cibuildwheel). Python was setup by `cibuildwheel` in a docker-container. But this error is also present when I use `apt`, build from source, or the setup python GitHub action.

Comment: @wjandrea I was running `pip install .` to install an extension module that was cloned from GitHub.

Comment: @mbs9 Then what's in `setup.py`?

Comment: @wjandrea I checked setup.py and I saw the problem immediately! Thank you so much for your comment! You saved me several hours of work! If you convert it to an answer, I will accept it as the solution.

Comment: Glad you found it; am sad that @wjandrea got here before me. Was going to say it sounds like you were using a package built for a different OS than what you've got, since the location of `site-packages` differs by OS: https://discuss.python.org/t/understanding-site-packages-directories/12959/5 That link and this one let you find the directory for your system: https://www.edureka.co/community/101278/how-do-find-the-location-of-my-python-site-packages-directory Am guessing the GitHub package was written on/for a specific system and was hacky, instead of using the standard installation hooks.

Comment: @mbs9 Glad I could help, but a suggestion is not an answer. As it stands, your question is likely to be closed as "resolved in a way that's unlikely to help someone else in the future", **but** you could edit the question to add how to reproduce the problem, then post your own answer. For example, you could post a public URL to the project and answer something like, *"Following wjandrea's suggestion to check `setup.py`, I found [this problem] and resolved it by [doing this]."*